# How to open a new form in button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i am using php where i am using ajax i am retrieving data from database without reloading page i am getting data on same page now i want that when i get data i retrieve in table format then there is update button there when i click on update button a new form should open

Here is code

**index.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun()
{
var exam=new XMLHttpRequest();
exam.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(exam.readyState==4)  
    {
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=exam.responseText;
    }
}
exam.open("GET","rat_test.php?name=pramod",true);
exam.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="form" name="form">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="button" onclick="fun();" value="getvalue" />
</td></tr>
<div id="res"></div>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**rat_test.php**

```
<table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
   </tr>
<?php
include("connection.php");
$sel="select * from info";
$res=mysql_query($sel);
while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{ ?>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" ></td>
    <td><?php  echo $fet['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $fet['name']; ?></td>

  </tr>
 <?php }
?>
</table>
<form action="" method="post" id="form" name="form">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="button" onclick="fun()1;" value="Update" />
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

here in test_rat.php a **update** button is available i want to open a new form on that update button button

How can i achieve this

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Either get the new form with ajax or create with javascript on the fly

Comment: how could i get could u please write some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not clearly mention what you want here ..

As i understand, you want open a form on click of update button to open a form

i did same ....

Just you need to update rat_test.php with below code...

```
<table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
   </tr>
<?php
include("connection.php");
$sel="select * from info";
$res=mysql_query($sel);
while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{ ?>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" ></td>
    <td><?php  echo $fet['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $fet['name']; ?></td>

  </tr>
 <?php }
?>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('updateForm').style.display='block'" value="Update" />
</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="updateForm" style="display:none">
<form action="" method="post" id="form" name="form">
    <table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text"></th>

   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text"></th>
   </tr></tr>
</form></div>
```

If you need more help ..please elaborate your requirement...

Comment: @when new form open  previous should hide

Comment: OK, You need to put an Id in previous form as id="preform" in index page and update rat_test.php  as line document.getElementById('updateForm').style.display='block',document.getElementById('preform').style.display='none'

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to get a new form from backend, or you use javascript to create a new form.
Before diving in please do some research on how to create elements using javascript.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g3dgxg0d/1/)

```
function makeForm(){
var ele = document.createElement("input");
ele.setAttribute("type","text");
ele.setAttribute("class" , "your class");
ele.setAttribute("name" , "username");

var ele2 = document.createElement("input");
ele2.setAttribute("type","password");
ele2.setAttribute("class" , "your class");
ele2.setAttribute("name" , "password");


document.body.appendChild(ele);
document.body.appendChild(ele2);
}
```